# How do I extract this using a regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following strings that I want to run a regex (Java) against:

```
a#d3d,b#3jjf,c#44k
c#999,b#a1a,a#11a
```

I want to extract the value following the "c#" and before the next comma (,).  I want to extract the value "44k" from the first line and the value "999" from the second line.  I thought the following would work:

```
.*c#(.*),.*
```

but it doesn't.  Oh, and an English explanation of the regular expression would help me to better understand your answer.

Comment: see this :  http://rubular.com/r/ckRwasekcd

Comment: what about c# in between, like b#a1a,c#999,a#11a, would you want to extract that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the advanced lookbehind version

```
(?<=c#)[^,\s]+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vvi7)

`(?<=c#)` is a lookbehind assertion, it ensures that there is `c#` on the left of the pattern.

`[^,\s]+` is a negated character class, together with the quantifier `+` it will match at least one character that is not  a comma or a whitespace.

Comment: You pattern is not capturing, maybe add some `( ... )`?

Comment: I don't use a capturing group, because I am matching only the relevant part, so the result is the complete match, no need for a capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

```
c#([^,\s]+)
```

That should do it. Find `c#` and then grab one or more characters that isn't a comma or a whitespace (means that end of line also ends the match).

Comment: if pattern is not multiline, \s won't match the enter.

Comment: No, Multiline only affects the anchors `^` and `$`. The `Pattern.DOTALL` option affects the `.`, making it match also the newline characters. [Methods of the Pattern Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)

Comment: This almost works...If I issue:  '.*c#(.+?)[,\$].*'  then it returns the "44k" value but not the "999" value.  I assume this is because of the leading ".*" since the c# delimiter is at the beginning of the line and has no leading characters.

Comment: Why don't you try what I told you to put, and not some weird concoction you made up by taking pieces of everyone's answers. Nobody told you to put a `$` inside `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`c#(.+?)(,|$)` use this regex
`.+?` is a lazy regex. It will match everything until it finds comma or end of the line.
And after that matcher.group(1) will return what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `(?<=c#)[a-z0-9]+` and got what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-greedy wildcard:

```
c#.*?(,|$)
```

The `.*?` means match any character zero or more times, but match as few as possible.
`(,|$)` means match comma or end of string.

Comment: I think you should substitute the `*` with a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```
(c#(.{3}[^, ]+)|$)+
```

This regex will match c# that is in the beginning and the last c# at the end of the string. c# in between the string would not be taken into consideration, i hope this is what you wanted.

for you to get the substring of the c# such as the "44k" or the "999", you would have to use a substring api in String java to retrieve the values from the regex.

Hope this helps